# File handling C++ , opening in ios::app mode, file getting wiped

Tags: c++, file-io

I am making a programme in turbo C++ which requires input and output to a file as well as retrieving the file data for later use.
`fstream file("playlist.txt",ios::in|ios::app);`

this is what I use but everytime i close the programme and run it again, all the previous contents get wiped. I thought ios::app "Sets the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation".
I tried ios::nocreate also, but to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `fstream::out` too:

```
fstream file("playlist.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
```

Then you can move file pointer to end of file. `in` and `app` can't be used together: you need to open for R/W because `app` implies you won't read.